# Minimum Hop Count in Directed Graph based on Conditional Statement

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

A directed graph **G** is given with Vertices **V** and Edges **E**, representing train stations and unidirectional train routes respectively.

Trains of different train numbers move in between pairs of Vertices in a single direction.

Vertices of **G** are connected with one another through trains with allotted train numbers.

A hop is defined when a passenger needs to shift trains while moving through the graph. The passenger needs to shift trains only if the train-number changes.

Given two Vertices **V1** and **V2**, how would one go about calculating the minimum number of hops needed to reach **V2** starting from **V1**?

---

[image: graph]

In the above example, the minimum number of hops between Vertices **0** and **3** is 1.

There are two paths from 0 to 3, these are

`0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 7-> 3`

`Hop Count 4`

Hop Count is 4 as the passenger has to shift from Train A to B then C and B again.

and

`0 -> 5 -> 6 -> 8 -> 7 -> 3`

`Hop Count 1`

Hop Count is 1 as the passenger needs only one train route, B to get from Vertices **0** to **3**

Thus the minimum hop count is 1.

---

**Input Examples**

Input Graph Creation

[image]

Input To be solved

[image]

---

**Output Example**

Output - Solved with Hop Counts

[image]

0 in the `Hop Count` column implies that the destination can't be reached

Comment: How many vertices and edges do you have in this graph? And how many trainIDs?

Comment: @JK, the number of vertices, edges and trainID's are 5000, 10000, and 10 respectively.

Comment: Fine, my algorithm should work for this. See answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming number of different trainIDs is relatively small (like 4 in your example), then I suggest using layered graph approach.

Let number of vertices be N, number of edges M, and number of different trainIDs K.
Let's divide our graph to K graphs. (graphA, graphB, ...)
graphA contains only edges labeled with A, and so on.
Weight of each edge in each of the graphs is 0.
Now create edges between these graphs.
Edge between graphs is representing a 'hop'
grapha[i] connects to graphB[i], graphC[i], ...
Each of these edges has weight 1.
Now for every graph run Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm from V1 in that graph, and read results from V2 in all graphs, take minimal value.
This way minimum of results for running dijkstra's for every graph will be your minimum number of hops.
Memory complexity is `O(K*(N+M))`
And time complexity is `O(K*(((2^K)*N+M)*log(KV)))`
(2^K)*N comes from fact that for every 1<=i<=N, vertices graphA[i],graphB[i],... must be connected to each other, and this gives 2^K connections for every i, and (2^K)*N connections in total.

For cases where K is relatively small, like 4 in your example, but N and M are quite big, this algorithm works like a charm. It isn't suitable for situation where K is big though.

I'm not sure if that's clear. Tell me if you need more detailed explanation.

EDIT:
[image]
Hope this makes my algorithm more clear.
Black edges have weight 0, and red edges have weight 1.
By using layered graph approach, we translated our special graph into plain weighted graph, so we can just run Dijkstra's algorithm on it.
Sorry for ugly image.

EDIT:
Since max K = 10, we would like to remove 2^K from our time complexity. I believe this can be done by making edges that represent possible hops virtual, instead of physically storing them on adjacency list.